# Convert numbers from Verilog to C

Tags: c, numbers, verilog

I wanted to convert this Verilog code [1] to C, and to do this, I needed to know what the equivalent of Verilog numbers [2] is in the C language?

```
[1]

//test procedure
reg signed[31:0]rdata_1=0;
initial begin
    while(rst)begin
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    wb_master_0.wr(0*4,32'h80,4'b1111);
    update_sb(0*4,16'h80);
    wb_master_0.wr(1*4,32'h5,4'b1111);
    update_sb(1*4,16'h5);
    wb_master_0.wr(2*4,32'h5,4'b1111);
    update_sb(2*4,16'h5);
    wb_master_0.wr(3*4,32'hf87,4'b1111);
    update_sb(3*4,16'hf87);
    wb_master_0.wr(4*4,32'h0,4'b1111);
    update_sb(4*4,0);
    repeat(1000)begin
        wb_master_0.rd(8*4,rdata_1);
        check_sb(8*4);
        rdata_1=rdata_1>>>8;
        wb_master_0.wr(4*4,rdata_1,4'b1111);
        update_sb(4*4,rdata_1[15:0]);
        
    end
    #10 $finish;
end
```

```
[2]

wb_master_0.wr(1*4,32'h5,4'b1111);

32'h5   --> in C?
4'b1111 --> in C?
```

Comment: Would you please show what you have tried (including research and stdies) so far?

Comment: @tshiono

We are trying to implement [this project](https://opencores.org/projects/pid_controller) in hardware/software co-design

Comment: Sorry for the misleading comment. I have not intended to ask about the background of the project. You are encouraged to try to solve your facing problem with your effort *before* asking for help. If you still have some specific questions after your attempt, then please come back with your own code and/or the result of your reasearch on the problem. BR.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking `32'h5` is just an unsigned 32-bit hexadecimal 5. And it is the same as a decimal `5u` or `0x5u` if you wish. `4b1111` is a 4-bit unsigned binary number which can be represented by decimal `15u`. There is no binary representation available in 'c'. In c++(2014) however, you can use `0b1111u`.

Verilog differs from 'c' in representation and use of the numbers. Whether in 'c' you can have integers of certain fixed width, like 8, 16, 32, 64 (or others depending on implementation), Verilog operates single bits and their bundles of arbitrary widths. In addition it has a set of rules for bit extensions, truncations and extractions. The way the number is used can alter the real width and as a result, can alter the value in the usage model. So, in order to get exact answer, the rest of the code is also needed.